# How to access HTML of a specific element returned by jQuery.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page in which when a user clicks on a specific element, a javascript function is triggered which uses $.post() (i.e. jquery) to send the user's data to a PHP script which modifies a database. 
On success, the PHP page simply prints

```
<p id='success'>Yay!</p>
```

On fail, it prints:

```
<p id='failure'>$some_error_message</p>
```

The callback part of the $.post then checks which of these exists. On success, it simply shows an existing (currently hidden) element. On failure, I want to grab the $some_error_message bit, and put it on my page.

I've found a way to do this (as below) but it's clunky - I am sure I shouldn't be having to use an ".each" function when I only want to access a single element. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
$.post('myURL.php', myData, function(retData)
{
  if ( $(retData).filter('#success') )
  {
     $('#mySuccessDiv').show(200);
  }
  else if ($(retData).filter('#failure') )
  {
    $(retData).filter('#failure').each(function()
    {
       $('#myErrorDiv').html($(this).html());
    });
  }
  else
    $('#myErrorDiv').html("Unspecified Error");
}, "html");
```

As I say, the use of .each seems wasteful, but I can't simply use

```
$('#myErrorDiv').html($(retData).filter('#failure').html());
```

because .filter returns a series of objects. But equally, I can't work out how to access only element 0 (since I'm filtering on ID, there can only be one match). I tried:

```
$('#myErrorDiv').html($(retData).filter('#failure')[0].html());
```

but it didn't like that.

Am I forced to use .each, or am I being really obtuse?

Comment: I'd strongly advise to return error status header from the server so you can use separate error and success callbacks. BTW in your last attempt you were close, just use `...filter('#failure').eq(0).html()` (working on jQuery object) or `...filter('#failure')[0].innerHTML` (working on a DOM node).

Answer (score 2):

[.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) will return a jQuery object(with or without any element), so it will always be truthy, to see whether it returned any element you need to check the length of the returned jQuery object

```
$.post('myURL.php', myData, function (retData) {
    var $obj = $(retData);
    if ($obj.filter('#success').length) {
        $('#mySuccessDiv').show(200);
    } else if ($obj.filter('#failure').length) {
        $('#myErrorDiv').html($obj.html());
    } else {
        $('#myErrorDiv').html("Unspecified Error");
    }
}, "html");
```

---

Another solution is to use [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$.post('myURL.php', myData, function (retData) {
    var $obj = $(retData);
    if ($obj.is('#success')) {
        $('#mySuccessDiv').show(200);
    } else if ($obj.is('#failure')) {
        $('#myErrorDiv').html($obj.html());
    } else {
        $('#myErrorDiv').html("Unspecified Error");
    }
}, "html");
```